# how to use fa icons in bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have implemented a bootstrap card, and in the body area of the card I have a list, what I need to do is to place fontawesome icons, instead of the default bullets, before my `p` tags, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="card mb-3" style="border-left: 6px solid #ffc200; ">
    <div class="card-header"><b>Smart Band with Gesture Control</b></div>
        <div class="card-body">
           <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Arduino Uno + Android app</h6>
           <ul class="fa-ul">
               <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span><p class="card-text">Wearable smart band</p></li>
               <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span><p class="card-text">control smartphone with simple hand gesture</p></li>
               <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span><p class="card-text">Heartbeat & temparature measurement</p></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add BootstrapCDN , to be able to use these icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly ok, you just need to change `fas fa-check-square` to `fa fa-check-square` and of course link to the fontawesome resources.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="card mb-3" style="border-left: 6px solid #ffc200; ">
<div class="card-header"><b>Smart Band with Gesture Control</b></div>
    <div class="card-body">
       <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Arduino Uno + Android app</h6>
       <ul class="fa-ul">
           <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span><p class="card-text">Wearable smart band</p></li>
           <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><p class="card-text">control smartphone with simple hand gesture</p></li>
           <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><p class="card-text">Heartbeat & temparature measurement</p></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `<p>` tag in the list unless you put everything inside it. It'll make a new line otherwise. This FontAwesome page discusses the best way to make lists-
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list

If you need another bullet icon before just add a separate icon before the first one by putting another `<i class="fa fa-class"></i>` (whatever icon class you want to use...) before (check if you want the `<span>` tags around the first `<i></i>` instead of the second).